# Sonar issue - parameter must be nonnull but is marked as nullable

Tags: java, collections, guava, sonarqube

I have written this predicate and sonar is complaining about it. I am not sure how to fix this violation. Please help:

```
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;

import java.util.Map;
public final class FooPredicate {

    private FooPredicate(){}

    public static Predicate<Map.Entry<Long,Long>> isFirstElement(final Long o) {
        return new Predicate<Map.Entry<Long,Long>>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(Map.Entry<Long,Long> foo) { 
                return foo.getKey().equals(o);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

It is complaining about the Foo parameter to the apply method.

> ```
> Dodgy - Parameter must be nonnull but is marked as nullable
> foo must be nonnull but is marked as nullable
> ```

The apply method is defined as taking a nullable and I can't do anything about that. So isn't Sonar and Guava fighting here?

```
> boolean apply(@Nullable
>             T input)
> 
> Returns the result of applying this predicate to input. This method is
> generally expected, but not absolutely required, to have the following
> properties:
> 
>     Its execution does not cause any observable side effects.
>     The computation is consistent with equals; that is, Objects.equal(a, b) implies that predicate.apply(a) ==
> predicate.apply(b)). 
> 
> Throws:
>     NullPointerException - if input is null and this predicate does not accept null arguments
```

Comment: Yes, different tools have different interpretations of @Nullable, and no matter what Guava does, some tool will complain about it.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing `foo.getKey()`. If `foo` is null that will throw a NullPointerException but you aren't declaring that `foo` must not be null.

Null check `foo` before you use it.

```
if (foo != null) {
   return foo.getKey().equals(o);
} else {
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Guava issue referring to this same thing: https://github.com/google/guava/issues/920